# JavaScript for loop does not check array and display message in specified html element

Tags: javascript, arrays

The leap year message doesn't displayed in specified element

Not sure why its not kicking the message after the for loop

```js
const year = [2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024, 2025, 2026, 2027, 2028, 2029, 2030, 2031, 2032];

for (var i = 0; i < year.length; i++) {
  if ((year[i] % 100 === 0) || (year[i] % 100 != 0) && (year[i] % 4 == 0)) { //Loops through the array 'year'
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = year[i] + " is a Leap year" + "<br>"); //add the message to the inner HTML of ID results
} else {
  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = year[i] + " is not a Leap year" + "<br>"); //add the message to the inner HTML of ID results
}
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Leap Year Array</title>

  <style>
    body {
      background-color: powderblue;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>Check Leap Year from an Array List</h1>
  <br>
  <p>This is my Array List: 2020, 2021, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024, 2025, 2026, 2027, 2028, 2029, 2030, 2031, 2032</p>
  <p>Result:</p>
  <p id="results"></p>

</body>
```

Comment: You have extra `}` characters in the JavaScript. That will cause an error.

Comment: Each time through the loop you replace the `innerHTML`. So at the end of the loop you just have the output from the last year in the array.

Comment: If you want to see all the years, you need to concatenate to the inner HTML, not replace it.

Comment: Plus your formula is wrong. The first check should be `% 400`.

Comment: Use `+=` instead of `=` to add to the end.

Comment: @Barmar Can you rewrite it so I can see it. I've updated the formula but I am not sure about the document.getElement part

Comment: Just change `innerHTML =` to `innerHTML +=`.

Comment: @Barmar. Still nothing is displaying

Comment: also leap years is not always after 4 years, sometimes is after 5 **!**

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of syntax errors that prevent the code from running at all. You have an extra `)` at the end of the assignments to `innerHTML`, and some extra `}` characters.

You didn't group the conditions in `if` correctly.

To add to the DIV, you need to use `+=` to append; `=` replaces the `innerHTML`.

In your `if` condition, the exception should be multiples of `400`, not `100`.

```js
const year = [2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024, 2025, 2026, 2027, 2028, 2029, 2030, 2031, 2032];

for (var i = 0; i < year.length; i++) {
  if (year[i] % 400 === 0 || (year[i] % 100 != 0 && year[i] % 4 == 0)) { //Loops through the array 'year'
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML += year[i] + " is a Leap year" + "<br>"; //add the message to the inner HTML of ID results
  } else {
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML += year[i] + " is not a Leap year" + "<br>"; //add the message to the inner HTML of ID results
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Leap Year Array</title>

  <style>
    body {
      background-color: powderblue;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>Check Leap Year from an Array List</h1>
  <br>
  <p>This is my Array List: 2020, 2021, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024, 2025, 2026, 2027, 2028, 2029, 2030, 2031, 2032</p>
  <p>Result:</p>
  <p id="results"></p>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you. I see that my small errors really added up. Very grateful for your help.